# Cannot Add User Control to AJAX Toolkit TabContainer

Tags: ajax

I have a user control called "Request" that I am able to display outside of a TabContainer on my SharePoint 2010 application page.  So the following works:

```
<UserControl:Request ID="Request1" runat="server" />

<Ajax:TabContainer ID="TabContainer1" runat="server" ScrollBars="None" Enabled="true">
    <Ajax:TabPanel ID="TabPanel1" runat="server" HeaderText="Request">
        <ContentTemplate>
            <asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" Text="Label">Mylabel</asp:Label>
        </ContentTemplate>
    </Ajax:TabPanel>
</Ajax:TabContainer>
```

However, if I merely move the UserControl line into the ContentTemplate section, replacing the existing Label control, the page bombs out with a runtime error and "Request failed".

Answer (score 0):

The workaround for me was to COPY, not MOVE, the user control into the ContentTemplate section, then give the copy a different ID and set the original (which I don't need) to visible="false".  I have no idea why this works and it looks like a bug to me.  If anyone can explain it, please do so...